# Python : verifying user's input?

Tags: python, list, input

My variable `userAnswerList[]` takes the user's input, and I need to verify if the user has input other than `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`.

Here's my code below, and wondering how should I validate user's input between the range of (`A` `B` `C` `D`) and if not print the error message?

```
answerList = ["A","C","A","A","D","B","C","A","C","B","A","D","C","A","D","C","B","B","D","A"]
userAnswerList = []
correct = 0
incorrect = 0

def main():
    for i in range(20):
        i = i + 1
        answer = input("Please Enter the answer for Question %d:" %i)
        userAnswerList.append(answer)
        numCorrect = [i for i in userAnswerList if i in answerList]

    if len(numCorrect) > 15:
        print("Congratulations You have passed the exam!")
    elif len(numCorrect) < 15:
        print("Failed....Please try again")

correct = len(numCorrect)
incorrect = 20 - correct

print("Correct Answers:",correct,"/ Incorrect Answers:",incorrect)  

main()
```

Comment: If your next question is going to be "ok, I figured out how to check if a variable is A B C or D. Now how do I go back and ask the user to try again?", this may be useful to you: [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23294658/953482)

Comment: thanks for the link ; I will try "try-except"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are already using the `in` syntax well. If you only want to check whether the answer is either A, B, C or D the following code would work.

```
if not answer in ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']:
    print("Invalid answer.")
```

This script can further benefit from Python's syntax as such:

```
if answer not in 'ABCD':
    print("Invalid answer.")
```

Comment: In Python it is more clear to do `answer not in [...]` than `not answer in [...]`.

Comment: If these are single-letter answers, you can even use `'ABCD'` instead of `['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']`.

Comment: yes, there are single-letter answers.. so should I try [ABCD] ?

Comment: You can test for membership (whether the answer is in the object you are comparing to) via `'ABCD'` or  `['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']`. The decision is purely style as they would give the same answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
import re

if re.match("^[ABCDabcd]$", answer) is not None:
    # Matched!
else:
    # Didn't match!
```

Comment: regex seems like overkill here. You can solve the problem using only built-in functionality.